# Обращение к файлу внутри jar

Tags: java

Есть jar, в процессе работы использующий xml-документ. В классе, получающем информацию из документа, есть такая строчка:

```
NodeList mainNodeList = parseXML("filelist.xml").getElementsByTagName("file");
```

При этом сам файл находится в корневой директории проекта. После создания jar обращение происходит к директории, в которрой этот архив находится. Соответственно, появляется вопрос: как должен выглядеть путь обращения к файлу, лежащему в самом архиве?

Comment: ошибки или еще что-нибудь? или Вы так и не собрали jar, а уже спрашиваете?

Comment: jar собрал, ошиббок нет. Просто не знаю, как обратиться к ресурсу внутри самого файла

Comment: ну jar это простой zip-архив, значит можно попробовать использовать ZipIntupStream

Comment: Как причитать файл то в конце концов внутри jar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для JVM корневым каталогом является каталог, откуда он запущен. В данном случае (если это не серверное приложение), то это каталог, где лежит JAR. Соответственно, чтобы добраться до файла, который лежит внутри JAR, надо либо использовать `ZipInputStream` или `JarInputStream`

В качестве альтернативы можно использовать читалку ресурса в виде

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("filelist.xml");
```

Правда, в этом случае filelist.xml должен лежать в корне CLASSPATH джара. Если вне CLASSPATH джара, то можно попробовать указать что-то типа `"../xml/filelist.xml"`.

Comment: спасибо, работает))