# В исполняемом jar не работает принтер

Tags: java, jar, принтер

Всем привет!
У меня такая проблема - при сохранении проекта в исполняемый jar, теряется функция отправки изображений на печать. Однако в ide работает отлично.
Суть проги следующая - при вводе номера артикула, автоматически распечатывается этикетка с нужным артикулом на термопринтере.
При запуске jar появляется интерфейс, но после введения артикула ничего не происходит.

Файл пакую через Project Structure - Artifacts, Build Artifacts.
Папка с готовыми файлами этикеток помечена как Resources Root.

Подскажите, от чего может теряться связь с принтером в jare?

```java
String str = jTextField.getText();
String result = str + ".jpg";

DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.JPEG;

PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(flavor, null);

DocAttributeSet aset = new HashDocAttributeSet();
MediaSizeName mediaSizeName = MediaSize.findMedia(58,40,MediaPrintableArea.MM);
aset.add(mediaSizeName);
aset.add(new MediaPrintableArea(0, 0, 58, 40, MediaPrintableArea.MM));
aset.add(OrientationRequested.PORTRAIT);
try {
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("resources/" + result);

    Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(inputStream, flavor, aset);
    if (services.length > 0) {
        DocPrintJob job = services[0].createPrintJob();
        job.print(doc, null);
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Решение найдено благодаря подсказке – Byb**

Заменила строку со стримом на:

```java
InputStream inputStream = 
his.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(result);
```

Comment: Вы же когда собираете проект, папка "resources" теряется, её вроде нет в итоговом jar-архиве, а программа на неё опирается (строка с `FileInputStream`). Поэтому в IDE работает, а в качестве jar-ника - нет. Вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403256/how-do-i-read-a-resource-file-from-a-java-jar-file?rq=1) вопрос о том, как можно прочитать файлы, находящиеся внутри jar-ника.

Comment: Какое же Вам спасибо! Всё получилось через внесение ресурсов в стрим!

Comment: Отлично, рад помочь)

Comment: Если вы нашли решение, то пожалуйста, опубликуйте его как ответ (:

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Доступ к ресурсам jar файла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1153337/); [Обращение к файлу внутри jar](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/83955/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заменила строку со стримом на:

```
InputStream inputStream = his.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(result);
```

Это решило проблему.

Comment: @zcorvid и в чём смысл вашей правки о_О ?